# How to do e2e test on formatted result?

Tags: angularjs

I am using filter to format a number, how do I go about testing it in e2e?

```
<td>{{unformattedNumber | number: 2}}</td>
```

I can write a test to get the value of unformattedNumber using binding. I am not sure, how to get the value of TD element? Am I suppose to name the TD element and the using jQuery, look for it and compare?
Thanks

Comment: I was wrong, it seems unformattedNumber does come with 2 decimal digits.

Comment: You could probably attach id to specific `<td>` and then select it to find what you need.

Comment: that is what I was going for, but it seems when pulling the data, the filter was already applied, which made my life easy now.